# what am i not doing right while using squarewaves?

Tags: continuous-signals, wave, digital-to-analog

[image]

I have been applying square waves at 40hz and 10 volts via a function generator amplified by a power amplifier by 2 times(2A) on a 6mm steel specimen.
My signals captured from the AE sensor are not quite as it should be.
Anyone know where am I making a mistake?

Hi there, so I apply a 40Hz, 10volts square excitation signal from a function generator, that is amplified by an AEG power amplifier 2 times, then it applies to the u-type electromagnetic with copper winding which magnetizes the u-type electromagnet and due to this, a magnetic field is generated on the specimen which is a Q235 steel. The acoustic emission (AE) R-150 sensor then catches the signal, preamplifies it to 60db, and feeds it to the computer for further analysis. The purpose is to apply a magnetic field to the specimen via a U-type magnet to study the internal structure of the steel specimen. In this case, the steel specimen has no deformations but in the future, I will be deforming the steel specimen via tensile testing and then applying the same method of magnetization again to compare the signals and extract parameters that can tell me about microstructure defects. The thickness of the specimen is 6mm, and the number of turns of the coil on a U-type magnet is 250. The original square waves are from the data with 2 readings, 1 is voltage amplitude (V) and the other is time (ms).

For reference, this is the paper which I am following royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsta.2019.0586

Comment: You should definitely provide more information about your problem here. You actually give nothing other than a couple of images. What are the “original” square wave signals, how do you generate them, how do you drive the apparatus (what kind of amplifier is this), what is this specimen you describe, what is your sensor (what does even AE stand for), what did you expect your sensor output to be and **why**, what is the purpose (what are you trying to achieve)? All those questions should be addressed one way or the other to varying degrees to help us understand the problem. For what (cont.)

Comment: (cont.’ed) it is now I could even tell you that the problem is the speed with which the earth rotates around its axis and be neither wrong nor right since we don’t know anything about your problem (so my answer could even be the correct or completely irrelevant).

Comment: Hi there, 
so I apply a 40Hz, 10volts square excitation signal from a function generator, that is amplified by an AEG power amplifier 2 times, then it applies to the u-type electromagnetic with copper winding which magnetizes the u-type electromagnet and due to this, a magnetic field is generated on the specimen which is a Q235 steel. The acoustic emission (AE) R-150 sensor then catches the signal, preamplifies it to 60db, and feeds it to the computer for further analysis. 
The purpose is to apply a magnetic field to the specimen via a U-type magnet to study the internal structure(cont.)

Comment: (cont.'ed) of the steel specimen. In this case, the steel specimen has no deformations but in the future, I will be deforming the steel specimen via tensile testing and then applying the same method of magnetization again to compare the signals and extract parameters that can tell me about microstructure defects. The thickness of the specimen is 6mm, and the number of turns of the coil on a U-type magnet is 250.
The original square waves are from the data with 2 readings, 1 is voltage amplitude (V) and the other is time (ms).

Comment: For reference, this is the paper which I am following
https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsta.2019.0586

Comment: Could you please go ahead and edit your question to include all that information you provided in the comments? They belong in the question and not in comments under it.

Comment: @ZaellixA I have added it to my question body.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer but too long for a comment:

1. Use standard debugging techniques: start with the most simple setup where the answers are known and the output of each device can be pre-calculated by hand. Verify each individual device against your expectation.
2. Your setup seems quite noisy. Figure out what is causing the noise and try to reduce it somewhat.
3. Your target waveform graph shows other voltages ($V_{RI} + V_{capacitor}$). Measure and graph those as well.
4. Despite there being a capacitor voltage I don't see a capacitor in your setup.
5. Read the data sheet of all devices that you are using and make sure you are operating everything in the correct range. Specifically look at the output impedance of the power amp and how it would react to large inductive load.
6. Come to think of it: measure the magnet's small signal inductance, resistance and stray capacity and compare to your target.
7. Your magnet looks pretty "hand-made". Consider rewinding it properly and gluing down the windings so they can't move or buzz.
8. Do a magnetic flux analysis of the coil and the core using the magnetic properties of your specific core material. What's your saturation curve like, and how far in saturation are you driving this thing (if at all)? Measure and compare against your calculation.
9. From the looks of it you get an asymmetric MAE response, i.e. the spike on one edge of the square wave is bigger than on the other. Look for asymmetries in your setup.

Comment: Hi Hilmar,
Thank you for the insightful recommendations. I think all the comments are of high importance. I already checked by hand each device separately to figure out the noise.

As for the other voltages (VRI+Vcapacitor), they are used for other purpose. This is the paper that I am following (https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsta.2019.0586), 
I got a similar signal as the paper in the case of sine waves and I am not using extra voltages, but for square, I am getting an additional pulse as can be seen in the picture above.

Comment: It would still help if you would graph ALL signals in your setup: after signal generator, power amp, before pre-amp (if the impedance allow it). How do your flux/saturation curves of your magnet look like and especially they hysteresis ?

Comment: I will implement the changes to my setup to plot the hysteresis of my specimen under magnetization. Thanks